# Passing a struct by value to a P/Invoked library on Linux 64-bit?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, g++, pinvoke

I'm trying to get the native dependencies for a C# library I'm using to compile on Linux x86_64. The code itself is platform-independent and compiles easily.

However, after first trying to run my project on Linux with the compiled dependency, I started getting strange results from the library and a segfault later on. After some investigation, it appears that the parameters on the P/Invoke functions were not being passed in the correct order. It seems as though they're being passed in backwards.

I've tried compiling the native dependency in a few different ways and explicitly defining different calling conventions. Nothing seems to work.

**C# extern method definition**

```
[DllImport(InteropUtil.PLATFORM_DLL)]
public static extern NavStatus dtqFindPath(IntPtr query
    , NavmeshPoint startPosition
    , NavmeshPoint endPosition
    , IntPtr filter
    , [In, Out] uint[] resultPath
    , ref int pathCount
    , int maxPath);
```

**Relevant C++ definition**

```
#if _MSC_VER    // TRUE for Microsoft compiler.
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport) // Required for VC++
#else
#define EXPORT_API // Otherwise don't define.
#endif

extern "C"
{

    EXPORT_API dtStatus dtqFindPath(dtNavMeshQuery* query 
        , rcnNavmeshPoint startPos
        , rcnNavmeshPoint endPos
        , const dtQueryFilter* filter
        , dtPolyRef* path
        , int* pathCount
        , const int maxPath)
    {
        return query->findPath(startPos.polyRef
            , endPos.polyRef
            , &startPos.point[0]
            , &endPos.point[0]
            , filter
            , path
            , pathCount
            , maxPath);
    }
}
```

**g++ compiler settings**

```
g++ -shared -o cai-nav-rcn.so.1 -g -fPIC -I Detour/Include -I DetourCrowd/Include -I Nav/Include Detour/Source/*.cpp DetourCrowd/Source/*.cpp Nav/Source/*.cpp
```

In the below output, the `dtqFindPath` line shows clearly the out-of-order parameters. `maxPath` should be 100 (`0x64`), but is 1298 instead. 1298 is the first `int` in the `startPos` struct. 100 is instead the value for `path`.

**Partial GDB output**

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fef64330740 (LWP 3923)):
#0  0x00007fef63823ce9 in waitpid () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000004ae448 in ?? ()
#2  0x0000000000503b8b in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000004226b2 in ?? ()
#4  <signal handler called>
#5  0x00007feef052339c in dtNavMeshQuery::findPath (this=0x5405610, startRef=88101520, endRef=4203419680, startPos=0x7fff5fd3975c, endPos=0x7fff5fd3974c, filter=0x7fef64176ec0, path=0x64, pathCount=0x44d6595341be38e0, maxPath=1298) at Detour/Source/DetourNavMeshQuery.cpp:958
#6  0x00007feef0534d19 in dtqFindPath (query=0x5405610, startPos=..., endPos=..., filter=0x7fef64176ec0, path=0x64, pathCount=0x44d6595341be38e0, maxPath=1298) at Nav/Source/DetourNavMeshQueryEx.cpp:234
#7  0x0000000041ec2140 in ?? ()
...
#17 0x0000000005405610 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I've already compared the sizes of the `rcnNavmeshPoint` and `NavmeshPoint` structs on both ends, they are the same. The parameters going into the P/Invoke call are in the proper order, checked with the debugger.

Might as well include that the library I'm trying to use is [CritterAI](http://www.critterai.org/).

So my question is this: What should I change to get the calling convention between these two pieces of code to match?

---

## Update

I isolated the problem. It's the structs that are not being passed properly. I've created a SSCCE to demonstrate this:

**interop.cpp**

```
#include <cstdio>

#if _MSC_VER
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXPORT_API 
#endif

struct s
{
    unsigned int a;
    float b[3];
};

extern "C"
{
    EXPORT_API void testStruct(s str)
    {
        printf("STRUCT NATIVE\n");
        printf("SIZE: %u\n", sizeof(s));
        printf("%u, (%f, %f, %f)\n", str.a, str.b[0], str.b[1], str.b[2]);
    }
}
```

**cs.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace InteropTest
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct v
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct s
    {
        public uint A;
        public v B;
    }

    public class Test
    {
        [DllImport("./test.so")]
        public static extern void testStruct(s str);

        unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            s mStr;
            mStr.A = 22;
            mStr.B.X = 33f;
            mStr.B.Y = 44f;
            mStr.B.Z = 55f;
            Console.WriteLine("STRUCT MANAGED");
            Console.WriteLine("SIZE: " + sizeof(s));
            Console.WriteLine(mStr.A + ", (" + mStr.B.X + ", " + mStr.B.Y + ", " + mStr.B.Z + ")");
            testStruct(mStr);
        }
    }
}
```

**Compiled with**

```
g++ -shared -o test.so -g -fPIC interop.cpp && mcs /unsafe cs.cs && ./cs.exe
```

**The output on my system**

```
STRUCT MANAGED
SIZE: 16
22, (33, 44, 55)
STRUCT NATIVE
SIZE: 16
22, (33.000000, 0.000000, 3.179688)
```

A few other tests are showing that structs are "skipped", where printing `str.a` will print out the value of the next non-struct parameter. The rest of the struct appears to be garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** The answer below addresses the original version of the question.

There only is one calling convention on Linux x86_64. It's known as [System V AMD64 ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI). Whatever the mismatch is, it is surely not in the calling conventions. Perhaps the struct declarations do not match, or there is something else wrong that we cannot see.

The next thing I would do, in your shoes, would be to write some simple test code. I'd write a C++ function that received a pair of `int` parameters. Check that they get passed in the correct order. Convince yourself that the calling convention is not the problem, and then dig deeper to find out the real cause of the problem.

Comment: I updated the question with an SSCCE isolating the problem. I kept the way the structs were defined on both sides the same, though they should have the same memory layout. Also, for as long as I've been on SO, I haven't asked very many questions. Would it be wise to change the title to reflect the isolated issue?

Comment: OK, you've done a good job there with the SSCCE, well done! The question is a little bit different now. What was a question about calling convention is now about passing of a struct. Anyway, I'll see if I can help. However, I'm a Windows person rather than Linux and don't know Mono. So, my attempts to help may not be very effective! On .net I'd declare the three floats as `float[]` and use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=3)]`. I'd also pass pointers to the structs rather than passing by value. Can you change the native to `const s *str` and the managed to `ref s str`?

Comment: Switching the `v` struct with a `float[]` didn't change much, but passing by reference did make the difference, so yes, that does work. The only issue is that a lot of the library's API passes small structs by value and it would take quite a bit of work to do. At this point, I'm thinking it may be a good idea to submit a bug report to Mono and see what they have to say.

Comment: This does look like a Mono bug. Or perhaps a corner of the ABI that does not have a single well specified convention. Passing structs by value is certainly prone to confusion on Windows. Perhaps it is so on Linux too. I'd always force them to be passed by ref. I'm not sure there is much more that can be done here.

Comment: Alright, submitted a bug report here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=12925

I'll wait for a bit and see what happens. Worst case scenario I'll just modify the library for my purposes.